# Why is my Java/Libgdx 9 second count down timer not working?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Hi I am trying to create a simple 10 second count down timer for my Libgdx game but it keeps printing 0.0 remaining.  When my screen starts I create a gotime variable to hold the initial start time.  I then set a target time variable targettime by adding 10000 to gotime.  Then surely it is just a matter of subtracting the targettime with current time but this isn't working.  I believe it is because for some reason my gotime and targettime are printing out the same timestamp in the logcat with a strange E number like the following 1.3980063E12.  I am using Time.Utils.millis() to get times.  Thanks.

```
gotime=TimeUtils.millis();
targettime=gotime+10000;
timeleft=targettime-TimeUtils.millis();
```

Comment: Try printing `timeleft` out to logcat. What do you get? Also, what code are you using to print the part that is giving you "0.0"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
boolean TimerRunning = true;

int Timer = 10;

new Thread(new Runnable() {


public void run() {

while(TimerRunning == true) {

Thread.sleep(1000);

if(Timer == 0) {

TimerRunning = false;

}
else {

Timer = Timer - 1;

}

}

}).start();
```

And then use A method too get the Variable Timer! and you be done!

Comment: Thanks thought I might have to use a thread but I still don't get why the other way wouldn't work.